# Send 2 transactions on same ETH address, one is pending after 1hour

Tags: transactions

simple question on Ethereum :

-can we make several withdrawals to the same ETH address?

-Or do we need one destination address for one withdraw transaction?

I made 2 transactions to the same ETH address 3 minutes apart, the first one went through and the second one is stuck, pending; however the later had a low transaction fee. It has been 70 minutes.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can make any number of transactions to the same address.
2. If you set a low fee transaction can be delayed. You can check the site https://ethgasstation.info/ for the recommended gas price.

You can use a wallet that provides a way to set the transaction gas price. Another feature is the ability to replace a pending transaction by another transaction with higher gas price.

Comment: Am I correct that replacing a transaction requires:
1) Using the same nonce
2) Using (preferably) higher amount of gas

Is it foolproof? Are there problems with replacing a transaction?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen You partially are correct 1) the nonce have to be the same, 2) "gas price" has to be higher. You have no guarantee of the replacement, it is possible for a miner to pick the older transaction first. A common replacement transaction is to send a transfer to yourself, with 0 value, with a higher gas price. Transfer between accounts have fixed gas of 21000, and usually have a better priority.

Answer (score 0):

Make new transaction with higher gas price and the pending transaction will be dropped.

Comment: *Only if the nonce is the same.